# SQL - Query from multiple references, or have more relations?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have the picture that relation model should be as simple as it can be. 'D' related to 'A' would be queried Using A->B->C->D id references (each 1:n refs).
[image]
But I was thinking, is there any case where someone should complicate things and create more relation(s) to save in performance (?), instead of querying from multiple references?
[image]

Comment: Remember that additional FK's add performance cost when INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. I'd start with the basic design.

Comment: @jarlh You're right, but at later state, is there any case where I should create the model pictured in latter picture?

Comment: if we are talking of datawarehouse or big data db the second model is probably a way to save in performance but on the other side the disadvantage it's that you have to manage. For medium database cases model 1 it's 90 % used because with the cost of a well organized query gives you also the result. Implementing the second would be also interesting

Comment: @BUcorp Thanks, but what do you mean by "it's 90 5 used"?

Comment: sorry 90% i meant

Comment: are you developing the second one?

Comment: @BUcorp I was developing 1st one, but was curious about the choices.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is better extra query or extra column in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727964/what-is-better-extra-query-or-extra-column-in-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I assume that the column in `C` would be called `D`, not `A`.

Second, you are violating one of the principles of normalization. The value `D` is being stored in two places (in both tables `A` and `C`), but according to your description it really means one thing.

What you are suggesting is a significant complication to the data model. It is very different to ensure that the `D` referred to by `A` matches the `D`. Enforcing this is hard.  Violations become a data error.

As for performance, joins on primary keys are usually quite fast.  Chains of such joins are usually not a performance bottleneck.

As for maintenance, you end up with very different ways of representing the same result set. This can complicate debugging code.

Relational databases are very flexible, and they definitely support such constructs. There may be some situations where such an approach is helpful (for instance, if there were a parallel database where the partitioning keys on the tables are on different columns). However, I would not call it a best practice or commonly recommended.

Comment: Yes, it should be D column, not A, my bad! What do you mean D is stored in 2 places? Do you mean that A & C could have different references to rows of D?

Comment: @H36615 the column D would be in table A and table C and therefore is a duplicate which is bad for a number of reasons, the main (IMO) being that there is potential for the value of  a row to differ between the two columns

Comment: @SEarle1986 actually got it now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you think it would be good idea to use the second model in _any_ situation, like in big data db that the other commenter suggested?

Comment: @H36615 . . . There might be some cases where it is desirable for optimization (other than the one mentioned in the answer, it is hard to think of one though).  It does make sense to have a record with *all* the ids -- a denormalized summary table for user access.  But that would be a separate table entirely.